# Script To Write Auto-Gen'd Google Doc URL To Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form that does two things upon hitting the Submit button.  First, it dumps that data into a Spreadsheet, then it autofills a Google Doc Template with the info from the Form.

In my script to autofill the Google Doc, I've grabbed the URL for the Google Doc.  But I need to write this URL into the last row of Column J in my Google Sheet.  Correction: using the getActiveSheet functions are fine, I forgot this script is running from the (Active) Google Sheet (apologies!).

Can anyone assist with this?  Here's a snippet of the script to get the URL:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var TimeStamp = e.values[0];
  var Technician = e.values[1];
  var Vendor = e.values[2];
  var xxx = e.values[3];
  var yyy = e.values[4];
  var SerialNumber = e.values[5];
  var AssetTag = e.values[6];
  var TicketNumber = e.values[7];
  var HostName = e.values[8];
  var DocumentLink = e.values[9];
  var Return = e.values[10];
  var Platform = e.values[11];
  var Summary = e.values[12];
  var URL = "";
    
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('aaa'); 
  
  //Put auto filled Google Doc into the appropriate Vendor Folder
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  if (Vendor == "111") {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('bbb')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(TicketNumber + ' - ' + SerialNumber, folder); 
  }
  
  if (Vendor == "222") {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ccc')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(TicketNumber + ' - ' + SerialNumber, folder); 
  }
   
  if (Vendor == "333") {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ddd')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(TicketNumber + ' - ' + SerialNumber, folder); 
  }
    
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

  //Get the url of the newly created Google Doc
  var url = doc.getUrl();
  //Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here

  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{EmailAddress}}', Technician);
  body.replaceText('{{TicketNumber}}', TicketNumber);  
  body.replaceText('{{HostName}}', HostName); 
  body.replaceText('{{SerialNumber}}', SerialNumber); 
  body.replaceText('{{AssetTag}}', AssetTag); 
  body.replaceText('{{Summary}}', Summary); 
  body.replaceText('{{Vendor}}', Vendor); 
  body.replaceText('{{URL}}', url); 


  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From your following situation in your question,

> Also this is a shared Google Sheet, so I can't use the getActiveSheet function, I'd need to reference the Google Sheet URL, I believe.

If you have the permission to write the values to the shared Google Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var url = doc.getUrl();
//Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here
```

#### To:

```
var url = doc.getUrl();
//Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###").getSheetByName("### sheet name ###");
sheet.appendRow([url]);
```

- In this modification, please set the Spredsheet ID and sheet name. By this, the value of `url` is appended to the next row of the last row of the sheet in the Google Spreadsheet.
- If you want to use the Spreadsheet URL instead of Spreadsheet ID, please modify `openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###")` to `openByUrl("### Spreadsheet URL ###")`.

#### References:

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

### Edit:

From the following replying,

> That doesn't seem to work to insert the URL into the last row of column J unfortunately. It looks like this script can use the Active Sheet afterall, I'll edit the OP.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var url = doc.getUrl();
//Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here
```

#### To:

```
var url = doc.getUrl();
//Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here

// var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###").getSheetByName("### sheet name ###");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname")
sheet.getRange("J" + (sheet.getLastRow() + 1)).setValue(url);
```

Or

```
var url = doc.getUrl();
//Script to write this URL into the Shared Google Sheet will go here

// This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639/7108653
Object.prototype.get1stEmptyRowFromTop = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
  const range = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, 2);
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  if (values[0][0] && values[1][0]) {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  } else if (values[0][0] && !values[1][0]) {
    return offsetRow + 1;
  }
  return offsetRow;
};

// var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###").getSheetByName("### sheet name ###");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname")
sheet.getRange("J" + sheet.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(10)).setValue(url);
```

Comment: This looks like it's adding a new row with the append function.  Do you know how to take the URL of the generated Google Doc and put it into the last row of column J in my sheet?  It looks like this script can use the Active Sheet afterall, I'll edit the OP.

Comment: @user1509059 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I proposed one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it didn't seem to insert the URL from the Google Doc into  column J (still empty).  Any other solutions?  Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: @user1509059 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `but it didn't seem to insert the URL from the Google Doc into column J (still empty)`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, the value of `url` is put to the next row of the last row of column "J". I apologize for this. So in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Actually I had a copy/paste error before.  I ran your code and it inserted the link on the next line down, so I removed the "+1" portion of your code and it worked like a charm!  Thanks so much, you are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

If you need to write the `URL` value into the last row of Column J in a shared Google Spreadsheet file, you can try this sample below:

```
function sample() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID_IS_HERE/edit#gid=0');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // access first sheet
  var activeSheet = ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  //Sample setValue() action to the shared sheet file
  activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("URL");
}
```

> **NOTE: You would need to have an editor permission on the Shared Google Sheet file that you're accessing**

### References:

- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [setActiveSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setactivesheetsheet)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work to insert the URL into the last row of column J unfortunately.  It looks like this script can use the Active Sheet afterall, I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that ended up working for me.

```
//Get the url of the newly created Google Doc
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("### Spreadsheet ID ###").getSheetByName("### sheet name ###");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname")
  sheet.getRange("J" + (sheet.getLastRow())).setValue(url);
```

Comment: From replying, I thought that you wanted to put the value to the next row of the last row of column "J". But from your this script, I understood that you wanted to put the value to the last row. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. I would like to study more.